# Carrierwave - development upload issues after adding S3/Fog for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I got my production rails 3 app setup to use Fog/S3 for storage while running on Heroku. In the process, I made a few changes to `/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`. Here's what it looks like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    config.root = Rails.root
    config.storage = :file
  else
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['MY_ID'],                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['MY_KEY']                        # required
    }
      config.fog_directory  = 'my-app'                     # required
      config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
      #config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
  end
end
```

Here's my `image_uploader`:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Uploads are working fine in production. Files are being uploaded to the correct destination in development, but I get this error when viewing an uploaded image:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/vendor/image/24/StoreB.png"):
```

I'm unsure of how to fix this. Am I missing something in my uploader? Help please? Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Code example that throws error:

```
<% @stores.each do |s| %>
        <div class="row">
                <div class= "col-xs-9 horz-cent">
                        <%= link_to image_tag("#{s.vendor.image}"), user_show_store_path(s) %>
                </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you getting the error in `production` environment or `development`. Also, share the code where you are trying to view the image OR are you trying `/uploads/vendor/image/24/StoreB.png` path directly in address bar?

Comment: Only in development. Added a code example above.

Comment: If your file was uploaded successfully in development environment then could you please share the `absolute path` for the same.

Comment: By absolute path, do you mean where the file is actually located? If so: application_name/uploads/vendor/image/24/StoreB.png

Comment: By absolute path I mean `application_name/.../uploads/vendor/image/24/StoreB.png`

Comment: Okay, yes then the absolute path is as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `config.root` as below

```
 config.root = Rails.root.join('public')
```

Currently the files are getting uploaded in `Rails.root` directory which are non accessible from the browser as they are not in `public` directory.

Comment: That worked, thank you! But what did this do exactly?

Comment: This made your files to be uploaded under `application_name/public/uploads/vendor/image/24/StoreB.png ` directory. Note public directory. Controller can access public files directly without specifying any routes.

Comment: Ah I see. So why does this work in production without routes? Something to do with this line?: `config.fog_public = false`

Comment: Read this https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Store-private-public-uploads-in-different-Cloud-Files-Containers-with-Fog